# How can I add two values of a row, and then put the result into a new cell?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

In Python, I have a dataset/frame with 2 values, column A has values of say, 10, 20, 30 and column B has values of 5, 10, 15 etc.

How can I add the value of each row of each column and have the result in a column next to it?

So essentially it will be column C that has the sum results, so the first row will add column A and B for a result in column C for 15, and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

simple addition will do

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `eval`
*making a copy by using `inplace=False`*

```
df.eval('C = A + B', inplace=False)
# create a copy with a new column

    A   B   C
0  10   5  15
1  20  10  30
2  30  15  45
```

*altering the existing dataframe by using `inplace=True`*

```
df.eval('C = A + B', inplace=True)
df

    A   B   C
0  10   5  15
1  20  10  30
2  30  15  45
```

Comment: Skinning cats again?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30],'B':[5,10,15]})
df = df.assign(C=df.A + df.B)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
    A   B   C
0  10   5  15
1  20  10  30
2  30  15  45
```

Comment: Special note on the difference between this answer and @StevenG's answer.  They both do a simple addition to calculate the new column `'C'`.  Where StevenG assigns a new column directly to the the dataframe, ScottBoston creates a copy of the dataframe that includes a new column `'C'`.  The advantage of using `assign` to create the copy is that it doesn't overwrite the existing dataframe.  This has many advantages, particularly while testing and prototyping as it allows you to see the results without altering you starting point.